# How to assign subdomain to my application deployed on Cloudflare

Tags: subdomain, cloudflare, namecheap

Hope you are doing well.
I purchased the domain `mydomain.xxx`.
And I deployed my application on Cloudflare and got the link `https://my-application.pages.dev`.
At the moment, I would like to add the subdomain `sub.mydomain.xxx` on Namecheap and assign it to my application deployed on Cloudflare.

I tried adding a new record (type: `CNAME Record`, host: `sub`, value: `my-application.pages.dev.` on Namecheap but it didn't work.

How can I do this?